# create combine unique index on two tables data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am trying to create join index on the basis of two tables data. Below two tables have one to one relation. If one record record came which has guest value true for mobile that is in contact_tbl.
I created unique index on contact_tbl(customer_id, mobile and type) but I want this unique should be if guest is false in profile_tbl.

As per below example id - 4 should not be inserted.

```
profile_tbl  
id  guest  
1   true  
2   true  
3   false  
4   false
```

```
contact_tbl  
id customer_id mobile type  
11   1    545454  1  
12   2    545454  1    
13   3    123541  1   
14   4    123541  1
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, I fail to understand your description.

Comment: to solve above issue we can write a select query that will check mobile= 123451 and type = 1 and guest= false, if no record found then create new entry in profile_tbl and contact_tbl. But instead of writing one separate query in code, I want handle this via unique constraints or procedure. so looking for such solution.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify. A comment is not enough.